# Python PBKDF2 using core modules

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel, cryptography

I'm trying to implement *pbkdf2* in Python 2.7/3.4 without needing the pbkdf2 module. (I'm also trying to avoid using classes.)

Any insight would be appreciated:

```
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
import hmac, struct, hashlib, sys

is_python2 = True if sys.version_info.major == 2 else False

def pbkdf_two(passwd, salt, iters=2048, keylen=64, digestmod=hashlib.sha512):
    """
    >>> hexlify(pbkdf_two(b'All n-entities must communicate with other n-entities via n-1 entiteeheehees', unhexlify('1234567878563412'), 500, 16, hashlib.sha1))
    '6a8970bf68c92caea84a8df285108586'
    """
    dgsz = digestmod().digest_size if callable(digestmod) else digestmod.digest_size
    if keylen is None: keylen = dgsz
    # Helper function which copies each iteration for h, where h is an hmac seeded with password
    def pbhelper(h, salt, itercount, blocksize):
        def prf(h, data):
            hm = h.copy()
            hm.update(data)
            return hm.digest()
        U = prf(h, salt + struct.pack('>i', blocksize))
        T = U
        for j in range(2, itercount+1):
            U = prf(h, U)
            T = "".join([chr( ord(x) ^ ord(y) ) for (x, y) in zip( T, U )]) \
                  if is_python2 else bytes([x ^ y for (x, y) in zip(T, U)])    # XORing
        return T
    L = int(keylen/dgsz) # L - number of output blocks to produce
    if keylen % dgsz != 0: L += 1
    h = hmac.new(key=passwd, msg=None, digestmod=digestmod )
    T = b""
    for i in range(1, L+1):
        T += pbhelper(h, salt, iters, i)
    return T[:keylen]
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Code Review! Just to clarify: Does this work as intended in its current state?

Comment: It does. It returns the correct data for the test (commented code). I am running this through iPython (2.7). Being quite new to coding, I've not tested edge cases, but it works in conjunction with [pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools)

Comment: That's good to hear and congratulations on writing a good first question. For future questions you might wish to reconsider the wording of "I'm trying to", which can make it sound like you've not successfully managed to get your code working. To be clear your wording is fine, but could reduce confusion in the future if you went with something like "I've implemented a..."

Comment: @NickUdell thanks! I'll do so in future posts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Review

1. The docstring doesn't explain what the function does, or how to call it, or what it returns. There's just a doctest.
2. If the code were reformatted to fit in 79 columns, [as recommended by the Python style guide (PEP8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), then we wouldn't have to scroll it horizontally to read it here at Code Review.
3. `hexlify` and `unhexlify` are only used by the doctest, so they could be included there.
4. `sys` is not used, so the import could be omitted.
5. The key derivation function is called [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), so I think the function would be better named `pbkdf2`, not `pbkdf_two`.
6. I don't think that having default values for arguments to this function is a good idea. The caller needs to think about these values, not rely on the defaults. Note that [RFC 2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898) doesn't specify any particular values.
7. We're not running out of letters, so why not `password` instead of `passwd` and `digest_size` instead of `dgsz`?
8. The helper function `pbhelper` is called from only one place in the code, so there's nothing to be gained by making it into a local function.
9. The fourth argument to `pbhelper` is named `blocksize`, but this is very misleading: it's actually the (1-based) *index* of the block.
10. The iteration variable `j` is not used in the body of the loop. It's conventional to name such a variable `_`.
11. Since `j` is not used, it doesn't matter what values it takes, and so it's simpler to use `range(iters-1)` instead of `range(2, iters+1)`.
12. Since `h` is always the same, there's no need for it to be a parameter to the `prf` function.
13. The `msg` argument to [`hmac.new`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html#hmac.new) defaults to `None` so there's no need to specify it.
14. If the code used [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray) instead of [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes) then it would be portable between Python 2 and 3 without needing a version test.
15. Instead of:

    ```
     L = int(keylen/dgsz) # L - number of output blocks to produce
     if keylen % dgsz != 0: L += 1
    ```

the number of blocks can be computed like this, using the floor division operator `//`:

```
    L = (keylen + dgsz - 1) // dgsz
```

1. But even more simply, why not just iterate until the result is long enough? That way you wouldn't have to compute `digest_size`, and it would have the advantage that in Python 3.4 or later, the caller could pass in the *name* of the digest algorithm, just as for [`hmac.new`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html#hmac.new).

#### 2. Revised code

```
import hmac
import struct

def pbkdf2(password, salt, iters, keylen, digestmod):
    """Run the PBKDF2 (Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2) algorithm
    and return the derived key. The arguments are:

    password (bytes or bytearray) -- the input password
    salt (bytes or bytearray) -- a cryptographic salt
    iters (int) -- number of iterations
    keylen (int) -- length of key to derive
    digestmod -- a cryptographic hash function: either a module
        supporting PEP 247, a hashlib constructor, or (in Python 3.4
        or later) the name of a hash function.

    For example:

    >>> import hashlib
    >>> from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
    >>> password = b'Squeamish Ossifrage'
    >>> salt = unhexlify(b'1234567878563412')
    >>> hexlify(pbkdf2(password, salt, 500, 16, hashlib.sha1))
    b'9e8f1072bdf5ef042bd988c7da83e43b'

    """
    h = hmac.new(password, digestmod=digestmod)
    def prf(data):
        hm = h.copy()
        hm.update(data)
        return bytearray(hm.digest())

    key = bytearray()
    i = 1
    while len(key) < keylen:
        T = U = prf(salt + struct.pack('>i', i))
        for _ in range(iters - 1):
            U = prf(U)
            T = bytearray(x ^ y for x, y in zip(T, U))
        key += T
        i += 1

    return key[:keylen]
```

Comment: `The iteration variable j is not used in the body of the loop. It's conventional to name such a variable _` Without going too much off topic, why _? I'm aware the console uses _ as the previous result, but am struggling to see the connection

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie It's just a convention. The two uses of `_` are not connected.